# OpenShift 4.x and HELM

Tags: openshift, openshift-4

What is the support of HELM in OpenShift 4.x?

In the documentation:
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/welcome/oce_about.html
"OpenShift Container Engine users have full access to Kubernetes Operators, pod deployment strategies, Helm, and OpenShift Container Platform templates."

But if you look for HELM in the documentation there are no entries, only talking about operators, but no plain HELM.

Is HELM supported in OpenShift 4.x? Any pointer to documentation about it?

What version of HELM?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helm is not supported in a way that you can call Red Hat support on, though the Helm Operator is a supported integration. Helm can be used just like any kubernetes based solution, just Red Hat doesn't provide a distribution of it. It is looking at doing it in the future, esp around Tiller-less Helm v3.

Answer (score 1):

> Is HELM supported in OpenShift 4.x? Any pointer to documentation about it?

AFAIK, you can use HELM chart on OCP4 either, because OCP is Kubernetes. But personally I think it's not supported, we can make sense like docker.io image does not be supported. For instance, we can also use non-RH container images on OCP wihout any issues, but it does not provide enterprise support.